# How to control the list of elements throw keyboard events

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, angularjs, keyboard-events

[image: UI image]
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-o1ra7c

After the user searches results, the user tries to use keyboard events arrows need to move down.

```
<div>
            
              
              <input onChange={handleSearchChange}/>
            
            <div css={countryDataCss}>
              {countryList?.map((country) => (
                <div key={country.countryCode}>
                  <span css={countryCss}>{country.countryName}</span>
                  <span css={countryDialCodeCss}>
                    {country.countryDialNo}
                  </span>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: The argument of your 'handleSearchChange' is an Event. You have the information about the key pressed there. Another solution is to use tab instead of arrow down, as this is the standard for navigation. To do this, you just have to make your option divs focusable by adding tabindex="0".

Comment: @SivaSai please share a stackblitz with the issue replicated and expected output on the stackblitz!

Comment: Hi @NarenMurali i have forked in https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-o1ra7c we have an input and list of all countries on click on arrows user should able to move to the respecive country and on click on enter the country should be selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the javascirpt event [`onkeydown`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp) which for react is `onKeyDown` which gives the required behaviour, please check the below stackblitz!

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
  const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState('SG');
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  const [selectedDialCode, setSelectedDialCode] = useState('+65');
  const countryCodeListResponse = [
    { countryCode: 'IND', countryDialNo: '+91', countryName: 'India' },
    { countryCode: 'SG', countryDialNo: '+65', countryName: 'Singpare' },
  ];
  const [countryList, setCountryList] = useState(countryCodeListResponse);
  function handleSearchChange(e) {
    const searchText = e.target.value.toLowerCase();

    if (countryCodeListResponse) {
      const updatedList = countryCodeListResponse
        .filter((el) => el.countryName.toLowerCase().includes(searchText))
        .sort(
          (a, b) =>
            a.countryName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) -
            b.countryName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText)
        );

      setSearchText(searchText);
      setCountryList(updatedList);
    }
  }

  const onSelectCountry = (code, dialCode) => {
    setSelectedCountry(code);
    setSelectedDialCode(dialCode);
    setSearchText('');
    setCountryList(countryCodeListResponse);
  };

  const onKeyDown = (event) => {
    console.log(event);
    switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 38: // arrow up
        if (activeIndex > 0 && activeIndex <= countryList.length - 1) {
          setActiveIndex((prev) => prev - 1);
        }
        break;
      case 40: // arrow down
        if (activeIndex >= 0 && activeIndex < countryList.length - 1) {
          setActiveIndex((prev) => prev + 1);
        }
        break;
      case 13:
        const country = countryList[activeIndex];
        onSelectCountry(country.countryCode, country.countryDialNo);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="search">
        <div>
          <span>{selectedCountry}</span>
          <span>{selectedDialCode}</span>
        </div>
        <input
          class="search-input"
          onKeyDown={(e) => onKeyDown(e)}
          placeholder="Search"
          value={searchText}
          onChange={handleSearchChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div class="list">
        {countryList?.map((country, index) => (
          <div
            onKeyDown={(e) => onKeyDown(e)}
            className={index === activeIndex ? 'active' : ''}
            tabIndex="0"
            key={country.countryCode}
            onClick={() =>
              onSelectCountry(country.countryCode, country.countryDialNo)
            }
          >
            <span>{country.countryName}</span>
            <span>{country.countryDialNo}</span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yzcpb4?file=src%2FApp.js)